# LDAP password authication from command line?

Tags: ldap

I am providing -w "LDAP server password" in commandline but i am getting error . ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49).

So basically I am trying to achieve this - A user can reset its password by running a small script but i don't want to expose LDAP password to him .  so storing it in script only .

A very simple script -

uid="$USER"

echo "Welcome" $uid ;

ldappasswd  -x -S -D "cn=xxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xxx" -W -h 'IP address of LDap server' "uid=".$USER.",ou=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxxx" -w "LDAP server password"

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this .

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use either `-w <newpassword>` to provide the password on the command line, or `-W` to get prompted, but not both. Also, you need to put options in front of arguments. Try `ldappasswd -x -w "LDAP server password" -S -D "cn=xxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xxx" -h 'IP address of LDap server' "uid=$USER,ou=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxxx"`. Note i removed the dots from around $USER, you need them in perl but not in the shell.

But note that if you put this in a script, your users will need read permission on the script, or the shell won't execute it. Which means they will be able to `cat` the script and see the password. One workaround would be to make the script rx to the root user only, and allow `sudo <yourscript>` without password. Also, noone will prevent a user from changing his `$USER` variable, so your script is easy to hack  - better parse the output of the `id` command, and make sure you don't use `root` if you do the sudo workaround.